# "borrowed value does not live long enough" when read file by lines

Tags: rust

I have some issue with borrowing,when read file by lines.
How to convert borrowed value(**line_ok**) to owned in this code?

When running the following code:

```
use std::fs::{File};
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader,Lines,Error};

fn read_lines(filename: &str) -> Result<Lines<BufReader<File>>, Error>{
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(BufReader::new(file).lines())
}

fn main() {
    let values1=vec!["a","asd"];
    let values2=vec!["b","csd"];
    let file_path="file.txt";

    if let Ok(reader)=read_lines(file_path){
        let mut previous : Option<&str>= None;
        for line in reader {//["a","ab","b","cb","asd","csd"]
            if let Ok(line_ok)=line{
                if values1.contains(&line_ok.as_str()){
                    previous=Some(&line_ok);
                }
                else if values2.contains(&line_ok.as_str()){
                    if previous.is_some(){
                        println!("{} is {}",previous.unwrap(),line_ok);
                    }
                    previous=None;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
    error[E0597]: `line_ok` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:19:35
   |
19 |                     previous=Some(&line_ok);
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
22 |                     if previous.is_some(){
   |                        -------- borrow later used here
...
27 |             }
   |             - `line_ok` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: As an aside: You can use `io::Result<T>` as shorthand for `Result<T, io::Error>`. It's also a good idea to return a generic return type from `read_lines`, `impl Iterator`, so that the signature doesn't betray your strategy for implementing the iterator. Combining the two, its signature would be `fn read_lines(filename: &str) -> io::Result<impl Iterator<Item = io::Result<String>>>`. The implementation can remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

[`Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html#impl-Iterator) is an iterator of `io::Result<String>`. You can't store a reference to the string produced by this iterator as it will go out of scope in the next iteration. You can change type of `previous` to `Option<String>` to make it work.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Error, Lines};

fn read_lines(filename: &str) -> Result<Lines<BufReader<File>>, Error> {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(BufReader::new(file).lines())
}

fn main() {
    let values1 = vec!["a", "asd"];
    let values2 = vec!["b", "csd"];
    let file_path = "file.txt";

    if let Ok(reader) = read_lines(file_path) {
        let mut previous: Option<String> = None;
        for line in reader {
            //["a","ab","b","cb","asd","csd"]
            if let Ok(line_ok) = line {
                if values1.contains(&line_ok.as_str()) {
                    previous = Some(line_ok);
                } else if values2.contains(&line_ok.as_str()) {
                    if let Some(prev) = previous {
                        println!("{} is {}", prev, line_ok);
                    }
                    previous = None;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `is_some`/`unwrap`, it is preferable to use `if let Some (p) = previous { println!("{} is {}", p, line_ok); }`