# Read file with BufReader line by line and put in HashMap error borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust, hashmap, readfile

I would like to read a file line by line and then process the words. I use HashMap and the entry API for that. However I get a 'borrowed value does not live long enough' error and am puzzled how to fix this.

```
  1 use std::fs::File;
  2 use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
  3 use std::collections::HashMap;
  4 
  5 fn main() {
  6   
  7   let mut wmap: HashMap<_, i32> = HashMap::new();
  8   let file = File::open("book1.txt").unwrap();
  9   let reader = BufReader::new(file);
 10   for (_index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
 11     let line = line.unwrap(); // Ignore errors.
 12     let words = line.split_whitespace();
 13     for word in words {
 14       println!("{}.:.{}", _index, word);
 15       *wmap.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
 16     }
 17   }
 18 
 19 }
```

The error I get is

```
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> example-words.rs:12:17
   |
12 |     let words = line.split_whitespace();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
15 |       *wmap.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
   |        ---------------- borrow later used here
16 |     }
17 |   }
   |   - `line` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

I am aware that this is very similar to [Borrowed Value Using BufReader and Lines in Extra Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67557498/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-when-read-file-by-lines). However I tried to do it all in one main function whereas the other example uses the extra function

```
read_lines(filename: &str) -> Result<Lines<BufReader<File>>, Error>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You just need an owned string instead of a borrowed slice -- replace `entry(word)` with `entry(word.to_owned())`

Comment: I see [Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a borrowed string slice (`&str`) to a HashMap that "lives longer" than the borrowed value `word`. For this to work the borrowed value would need to have the same lifetime as your HashMap OR the HashMap needs to have ownership of the value inside of `word`. Here's an example:

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
  let mut db = HashMap::new(); //initialize mutable hashmap outside of the loop
  loop{
    //I start a loop to take in multiple key val arguments from the
    //command line but this means each iteration of the loop will 
    //clean up heap variables and any &str borrowing from these 
    //variables will be invalid after each iteration and the rust
    // borrow checker will let us know if we are trying to access
    // these invalid references, hence the compiler error 

    let mut string = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut string).unwrap();
    let command: Vec<&str> = string.trim().split(" ").collect();
    db.insert(command[0], command[1]);
  }
}
```

I end up with the same compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `string` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:9:30
   |
9  |     let command: Vec<&str> = string.trim().split(" ").coll...
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
10 |     db.insert(command[0], command[1]);
   |     --------------------------------- borrow later used here
11 |   }
   |   - `string` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is because on every iteration of the `loop` the string slice I intend my HashMap to borrow gets dropped (goes out of scope and is no longer valid) and rust keeps us from having dangling references. Instead change the `db.insert(command[0], command[1])` to `db.insert(command[0].to_string(), command[2].to_string())`. This will convert the &str -> String which will then be "owned" by the HashMap instance and survive for the remainder of the running
program. In your case:

```
use std::fs::File;
  use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
  use std::collections::HashMap;
  
  fn main() {
    
    let mut wmap: HashMap<_, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let file = File::open("book1.txt").unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for (_index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
      let line = line.unwrap(); // Ignore errors.
      let words = line.split_whitespace();
      for word in words {
        println!("{}.:.{}", _index, word);
        *wmap.entry(word.to_string()).or_insert(0) += 1;
      }
    }
  
  }
```

this will compile and run :)
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @cdhowie, you need to own the string using `word.to_owned()`.
While it is not an error, Rust naming conventions say that an underscore in front of a variable implies that it is not used, so I renamed `_index` to `index` as well.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let mut wmap: HashMap<_, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let file = File::open("book1.txt").unwrap(); 
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = line.unwrap(); // Ignore errors.
        let words = line.split_whitespace();   
        for word in words {
            println!("{}.:.{}", index, word);
            *wmap.entry(word.to_owned()).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
    }
}
```